# How to delete older rows with same ID and different timestamp in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table, simplified version below:

```
ID    Col1        Col2              CreatedDate

232   my data     some data        2017-10-15 8:50:20
232   my data     some data        2017-10-14 8:52:20
232   my data     some data        2017-10-13 8:53:20
232   my data     some data        2017-10-12 8:55:20
232   my data     some data        2017-10-11 8:54:20
```

`ID` is `int` and `CreatedDate` is `datetime`

I want to keep the most recent two rows and delete all other with the same id.  I will get `ID` from old.ID in the trigger (e.g., where `ID=old.ID` ).

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will delete everything except the last two record of the ID `old.ID` of your trigger.

```
DELETE FROM `mytable`
WHERE ID = old.ID AND CreatedDate not IN ( -- Delete rows ID = old.ID  but not in the subquery
  SELECT CreatedDate
  FROM (
    SELECT CreatedDate -- This select the last 2 from old.ID
    FROM `mytable`   
    WHERE ID = old.ID
    ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
    LIMIT 2 -- keep last two record
  ) foo
)
```

Comment: Accepted this answer because it was more closer to my needs than other answers, even though the other two answers also based on the same core syntax.  I would replace `232` in the query by `ID = old.ID` (its in a trigger).

Answer (score 3):

In My sql there is no option to using LIMIT in subquery, so you need to create as below:

```
delete from table_name 
where 
CreatedDate not in
  (select CreatedDate from 
            (select * from 
                      table_name 
                        where id='232' order by CreatedDate desc limit 2) as t);
```

Comment: OP want to do it for every IDs automatically. Id 232 is only a sample data.

Comment: @RickyNotaro-Garcia its ok.  I can handle `ID` easily.  I know the variable to put instead of 232.

Comment: @Santhosh I will try this but I don't see where it is limiting to `2`

Comment: You can create it as stored procedure and pass distinct of ID as parameters to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

This will keep the most two recent data of every id.

```
DELETE FROM `mytable` WHERE ID and CreatedDate NOT IN(
        SELECT CreatedDate
        FROM (
            SELECT max(CreatedDate) AS CreatedDate,
            max(ID) AS ID FROM mytable GROUP BY ID

            UNION 

            SELECT max(CreatedDate), max(ID) 
            FROM mytable 
            WHERE CreatedDate not in
            ( 
                SELECT max(CreatedDate) as CreatedDate
                FROM mytable GROUP BY ID
            ) GROUP BY ID
            ) foo
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use this query ,

`delete from table Where CreatedDate not in (
SELECT  CreatedDate FROM table order by CreatedDate Desc limit 2  )`

If it shows error of version then you can go with ,

`delete from  table WHERE CreatedDate not in 
       (
         SELECT * FROM (
          SELECT  CreatedDate FROM  table order by CreatedDate Desc limit 2
       ) 
      as t);`

Comment: OP needs to keep the most recent two rows and delete all other for each id.

Comment: Yes, `ID` has to be in where clause. But I can play with it now.  Mysql doesn't seem to like `LIMIT 2` so finding out how to change it to mysql format.

Comment: id is same for all , So I don't think it will effect on result

Comment: I am getting the error `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`. Using mysql 5.7.20

Comment: I have given another query option for version issue

Comment: @DaminiSuthar yes that one seems to have the correct syntax.  I think `select *` should be `select createddate`.

Comment: @AllenKing `Select *` is for to get subquery data

Comment: @DaminiSuthar my bad yes you are right.  Subquery will only return one column hence select * is fine.  I upvoted. Thank you.